# NodeJS Server getting stop on Error

Tags: node.js, google-speech-api

I am very New to NodeJS. I am developing Live Streaming based Speech to text for my web application. It works well but problem is

Sometimes, Nodejs throws an error as 'Request Time-Out' and http server has been stop. then I need to manually re run program again (with command `node app.js`)

I had used [this](https://github.com/vin-ni/Google-Cloud-Speech-Node-Socket-Playground) example here.

Screen shot is bello
Please help. And thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: `try{} catch (e){}` your errors. `. Thats normal if it fails. Thats how nodejs works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need first to `try {} catch(ex){}`your exceptions.
You may also use **[pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/)** which can handle that autostart if it crashes.
When using pm2 please make use of **--max-memory-restart** option otherwise the app can indefinitly restart and will slow down your server. That option can help you specify the amount of memory the autorestart can consume.

**Install pm2**

```
npm install -g pm2
//or
yarn global add pm2
```

**Run the app**

```
pm2 start app.js --max-memory-restart 100 --name node-speech
```

Using pm2 is even recommanded on the repository readme

Answer (score 7):

you can always have a global error handler, so that, your project won't fail and also you can take an appropriate action:

```
process.on
(
    'uncaughtException',
    function (err)
    {
        console.log(err)
        var stack = err.stack;
        //you can also notify the err/stack to support via email or other APIs
    }
);
```